# Using a Raycaster to get the intersection coordinates from the player's view?

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I'm having trouble getting the coordinates of where the player is looking in the world using a Raycaster. It's not picking up on any intersections.

More specifically, I'm trying to get the coordinates of the intersection on the terrain, which is made up of multiple BufferGeometry meshes. Here's the code I'm using taken from the [Raycaster example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_terrain_raycast.html): (`groupedMeshes` array stores the BufferGeometry meshes)

```
var mouseX = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
var mouseY = -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouseX, mouseY, camera.near );

// Convert the [-1, 1] screen coordinate into a world coordinate on the near plane
var projector = new THREE.Projector();
projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

// See if the ray from the camera into the world hits one of our meshes
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( groupedMeshes );
lastIntersects = intersects;

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    console.log("Intersection!");
}
```

And an image showing the player's view:
(The red dot explaining that I want to cast a ray from the center of the camera to the terrain)

[image]

The mouse/pointer is locked (1st person camera view) so I'm assuming I want to check for an intersection at the center of the screen? The code above doesn't do that so I've been testing without locking the pointer.

If anyone could see why it's not detecting any intersections, I would really appreciate the help. Thanks.

---

**EDIT:**
Seems I should be using `raycaster.intersectObjects( groupedMeshes );` not `raycaster.intersectObject( groupedMeshes );`. My bad.

So my only question now is how do I shoot the ray from the player's (first person) view to the terrain. Thanks!

**EDIT2:**

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0.5 );

var projector = new THREE.Projector();
projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( groupedMeshes );
lastIntersects = intersects;

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    console.log(intersects);
}
```

Comment: The three.js example you referenced appears to need updating... In any event, if I understand what you want to do, try `var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0.5 )` to raycast from the screen center always. Also, see if you can rewite your code to avoid 'new' in the render loop -- that is, reuse your objects.

Comment: Yeah, the code is used in a MouseDown event. Basically, trying to get the coordinates of the block the player is looking at and then remove it when the mouse is clicked (Minecraft-style). AFAIK, shooting a ray from the center of the screen to wherever the camera is looking would allow me to get these coordinates. Using the code in the new edit brings up some intersections but it doesn't seem to be where the player is looking. (Can look no mesh at all, and it'll still say there's a intersection) Should this involve looking at the camera's rotation? Thanks.

Comment: Best tutorial I've found and used on object picking: http://soledadpenades.com/articles/three-js-tutorials/object-picking/

Comment: Can you provide a simple live example?

Comment: Worked it out and added an answer. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked it out from looking at [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/PointerLockControls.js) script.

I'm now using this, which allows me to shoot a ray from the location of the camera in the direction player/camera is facing:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var direction = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -1 );
var rotation = new THREE.Euler( 0, 0, 0, "YXZ" );

function shootRay() {
    rotation.set( pitchObject.rotation.x, yawObject.rotation.y, 0 );

    raycaster.ray.direction.copy( direction ).applyEuler( rotation );
    raycaster.ray.origin.copy( yawObject.position );

    var intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects( groupedMeshes );
    if ( intersections.length > 0 ) {
        console.log(intersections[0].point);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is pitch and yaw object?

Comment: i would like to reiterate: what is pitch and yaw object?